# Laravel: modal parameters

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I'm following [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XnLTZ557qMegqRmWVwU?p=preview) example in my Laravel application. I have included the js file in the layout file as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/test.js") }}"></script>
```

The test.js file has following content (exactly as in the Plunker file):

```
    $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

            var $modal = $(this),
                esseyId = e.relatedTarget.id;
                $modal.find('.edit-content').html(esseyId);

    });
```

In my view file I have (exactly as in the Plunker file) the following:

```
<div><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="w" data-target="#edit-modal">Edit 1</a></div>
<div><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="q" data-target="#edit-modal">Edit 2</a></div>
<div><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="d" data-target="#edit-modal">Edit 3</a></div>


<div id="edit-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

On the page that needs to show the dialog box, I'm sure the test.js is loaded as I can see the content of the js file (using view page source).

While in the Plunker example, the content is shown depending on the link once clicks, I always see the ... instead of the id's from the 'a href'.

Looks like the JS is not inserting the html content into the modal-body edit-content area. Any suggestion on how to debug this?

**Updated - Solution:**

Fixed a small typo. Code above is now fully correct and works.

Comment: Try to use `asset("/scripts/test.js")` instead of `asset("assets/scripts/test.js")`

Comment: This suggestion does not work. I'm sure the JS file is loaded as the alert statement fires off.

Answer (score 0):

try .append instead .html

http://api.jquery.com/append/

before that, check if the desired value is being assigned to the variable - esseyId, by giving an alert()

Comment: Interesting. When I insert an alert statement in the js file after the first line, it does not show the alert. Replacing the entire javascript file with 1 alert statement, shows the alert.

Comment: e.relatedTarget.id - you should check this part i think. If you can get the required element by id and see, it might work...

Comment: I changed the original question with an update. Fixed now.